# I am trying to remove duplicate consequtive elements and keep the last value in data frame using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop-duplicates

There are two columns in the data frame and am trying to remove the consecutive element from column "a" and its corresponding element from column "b" while keeping only the last element.

```
import pandas as pd
a=[5,5,5,6,6,6,7,5,4,1,8,9]
b=[50,40,45,87,88,54,12,75,55,87,46,98]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a,b)), columns =['Patch', 'Reward'])
df=df.drop_duplicates(subset='Patch', keep="last")
df = df.set_index('Patch')
print (df)
```

when I run this I get:

```
       Reward
Patch        
6          54
7          12
5          75
4          55
1          87
8          46
9          98
```

however, what I want is:

```
Patch      Reward
5           45
6           54
7           12
5           75
4           55
1           87
8           46
9           98
```

PS: I don't want the duplicate elements repeating after another element or later in the series to be removed, but remove only consecutive duplicates while keeping the last to appear in the consecutive appearance.
I also don't want it to be sorted, they should appear in the same sequence as in the list.

Comment: groupby patch, keep the last element of each group?

Comment: @ddg I guess by grouping I will lose the original index of the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new column assigning an id to each group of consecutive elements and then doing the `groupby` operation followed by `last` aggregation.

```py
a=[5,5,5,6,6,6,7,5,4,1,8,9]
b=[50,40,45,87,88,54,12,75,55,87,46,98]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a,b)), columns =['Patch', 'Reward'])
df["group_id"]=(df.Patch != df.Patch.shift()).cumsum()
df = df.groupby("group_id").last()
```

Output

```
Patch  Reward 
5      45
6      54
7      12
5      75
4      55
1      87
8      46
9      98
```

Comment: shows an error TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: sorry, but when I put print(df) in the code and execute it, the original df gets printed and not the desired one.

Comment: Assign the dataframe. `df = df.groupby("group_id").last()`. Edited the code snippet as well.

Comment: What if you wanted to group by two columns?

Comment: @jonboy `df.groupby(["group_id1", "group_id2"]).last()` should do it